# jQuery isotope layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm having trouble converting my isotope 1.5 script to work with isotope 2.2. here's the old:

```
var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-grid'),
    $gridImages = jQuery('.portfolio-grid img');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () { 
        $container.isotope({
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            animationEngine: 'best-available',
            resizable: false, 
            transformsEnabled: true, 
            animationEngine: 'best-available', 
            itemSelector: 'li.portfolio-item', 
            onLayout: function() { jQuery(window).trigger("scroll"); }  
        });
            $gridImages.load(function () {
            $container.isotope('reLayout'); 
        }); 
    });

    jQuery(window).bind('resize load', function(){ $container.isotope('reLayout');  });

    $gridImages.lazyload({failure_limit: Math.max($gridImages.length - 1, 0)});
```

which works pretty well and here's the new

```
    var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-grid');
    var $gridImages = jQuery('.portfolio-grid img');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() { 
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',              
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            resizable: false
        }); 
        $container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function( ) { jQuery(window).trigger("scroll");  } );
        $gridImages.load(function () { $container.isotope('layout'); });                        
    });     
    jQuery(window).bind('resize load', function(){ $container.isotope('layout');  });
    $gridImages.lazyload({failure_limit: Math.max($gridImages.length - 1, 0)});
```

but I'm experiencing odd behavior, like holes in the grid layout (only at some very specific browser width) and, sometimes, the console error "cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempt to call 'layout'" (but that only *sometimes* and when I refresh the page. not on hard reload).

am I missing anything?

http://dev.jumpcutcreative.com/

Answer (score 0):

To fill holes in you might want to try the [packery layout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html) of isotope.

```
layoutMode: 'packery'
```

As far as the console error you mentioned, I was not able to replicate it even after refreshing a few dozen times. Maybe it's occurring because sometimes it's running `function(){ $container.isotope('layout');` on page load before `$container.imagesLoaded` is triggered. I would assume the images are the last things to load on the page so `jQuery(window).bind('resize load')` and `$container.imagesLoaded` would trigger at the same time and maybe sometimes `jQuery(window).bind('resize load')` would execute first causing the error.

Comment: thanks tovly. the console error still shows but it doesn't seem to have much effect. actually, I just realized that the error only throws when I click into the browser address bar and hit the ENTER key on my keyboard. then it shows the error at least every other time. clicking the 'reload' button or COMMAND+R works without error!   Anyway. I got the layout to close up tightly by using fixed dimensions for my images now (no %-based sizes).  I'm sure I have to start another thread but one issue I noticed now is that Firefox still leaves 1px gaps in between some images... not sure how to fix that